# How can a Perl web crawler follow an ASP.NET postback?

Tags: asp.net, perl, web-crawler, lwp

I'm building a webcrawler in Perl/LWP. How can the webcrawler follow a link in a ASP.NET grid like this:

```
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_listResult_Top_LnkNextPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$listResult$Top$LnkNextPage','')">Next</a>
```

Comment: +1, because regardless of my reservations of it being unanswerable, if it is actually answerable, I want to know too

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a WWW::Mechanize subclass called [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Scripter) with [javascript](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript) and [ajax](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Scripter::Plugin::Ajax) plugins that should be able to do this.  Haven't tried that particular approach.

The other alternative is [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Selenium), which works great but may be too much overhead/setup for you.

Answer (score 1):

See [CPAN module HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilderX::ASP_NET).

Comment: It almost makes sense that there's a CPAN module specifically to deal with this sickness :)

Answer (score 0):

Use WWW-Mechanize-Firefox, it is able to retrieve/follow any links that Firefox could.

You need to install mozrepl addon to firefox and the perl module will be connect to that addon and use firefox to open the links.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)

Examples: [http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Examples](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox%3a%3aExamples)